# reset a diverged branch to head of master, commit, then create a pull request with GitHub actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm using the following gh action to reset a beta branch to the head of master:

```
name: Reset Beta Branch

on:
  workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  resetBeta:
    name: Reset Beta Branch
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: master
      - id: commit
        uses: pr-mpt/actions-commit-hash@v2
      - name: Checkout Beta Branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: beta
      - name: Get Current Branch Name
        run: git branch
      - name: Set Git User
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
      - name: reset branch to master
        run: |
          git fetch --all
          git reset --hard origin/master
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          title: Changes by reset-beta-branch action
          body: Reset beta branch back to head of master ${{ steps.commit.outputs.short }}
          add-paths: .
          commit-message: resetting beta branch to master
          branch: reset-beta
          delete-branch: true
```

here's the PR that the action created https://github.com/aphexlog/dog/pull/10/files#diff-7829468e86c1cc5d5133195b5cb48e1ff6c75e3e9203777f6b2e379d9e4882b3

expected result:

- the diff should show that the file `test.txt` is being deleted from the `beta` branch

actual result:

- `test.txt` does not show up in the diff but is gone from the `reset-beta` branch that is being merged into the `beta` branch

Comment: Using `git reset` lets you pretend some commits never happened. This does not seem to be what you want; if that's the case, remove the `git reset --hard origin/master` entirely, and instead, make a *new* commit. There will be GitHub Action interactions here that I don't understand properly (I'm no GitHub Actions guru) so you'll probably need more than just this, but it's the `git reset` that I believe is the culprit in the behavior you have now.

Comment: There are specific file modifications that were committed to beta & must be reverted to the current state of master. the new commit must be exactly equal to the current head of master.

Comment: If you remove commits, though, you'll change the diffs you see: files that were added, then deleted, no longer show up because they *weren't* added-then-deleted any more. Remember that each commit represents the *full state of all files*, and if you want to revert some file to some earlier format or remove it but keep changes that were made, you must keep the intermediate commits. That is, you *add a new commit* in which the file's state is reverted.

Comment: If I am understanding what you are saying properly, I'd say that there are no intermediate commits that I wish to keep, because I just need to reset a branch to the current head of master.. basically as an alternative to just deleting its and re-adding it (basing it off master)

Comment: That's reasonable enough, but then apparently you'll need to change the expected result. (Hard to say for sure without looking more closely.)